# Calling layout from the view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, layout, view

I'm trying to use my layout which is in shared folder from my view, but it steel show the empty page in my browser like that :
 Razor_learning.Models.Product Product  Kayak
Here I have 2 questions:
1. why I get my name space name (Razor_learning.Models.Product Product) while I didn't mention it in my view or even in my controller and import view page ?
2.why my razor can't understand my layout ?
Here is my code iv view:

```
@Model Product
@{
    Layout = "_BasicLayout";
    ViewBag.Title= "producName";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

    @Model.ProductName

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my code in _BasicLayout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <style>
        #mainDiv {
            padding:20px;
            border:solid medium black;
            font-size:20pt
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, I hope someone can help me here.

Comment: To start with , if your view is strongly typed to `Product` class, it should be `@model Product`, not `@Model Product`. And no need to have tags like `html`,`head` and `body` in your view file if your layout already has those. What is happening currently ? Are you getting any error ? or you are getting the view result with markup from the view, but nothing from the layout ?

Comment: dear @Shyju actually I got my mistake Model Product should be model Product Thanks for that , this was the first question answers. I deleted my extra code in view but still can't understand my layout. I didn't get error I just getting   the view result with markup from the view, but nothing from the layout

Comment: remove all the html and body tag from the view because you have that in your layout . Also give the full path to layout (ex : `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_BasicLayout.cshtml";
}`)

Comment: Yes worked @Shyju thanks